# Particle Fading

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

So I'm using an object as the render type for my particle system, but I'd like for it to fade in when it spawns and out before it despawns. I'd also like to control how long it takes to fade in and for it to fade out. I believe this would have to use the Particle Info node, but I've had somewhat less than zero success.

Would somebody please mind solving this puzzle on making particles fade in and out?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this Node Setup to make the fade in and fade out, just connect your particle material instead of the emission material and use the color-ramp to adjust the fade in and fade out

[image]

Comment: I think this works pretty well! If you don't mind, could you please explain a little on how exactly the ColorRamp is used in this case?

Comment: Sure, the Age tells how many frames a particle has existed, and the lifetime sets the maximum time a particle can exist. Since you need to normalize the age to an interval between 0 and 1, being 1 the maximun time a particle can exist, you divide the Age by the Lifetime and plug it into a Color Ramp. The Color Ramp allows you to control when the material should be transparent (black color) or be the other material (white color).